# How to correctly add tracking tag for Google Analystics and Google Ads on the same page

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-script

I'm trying to add the script tags for Google analytics and Google ads to the same page.

Both Google analytics and Google ads give me pretty much the same script tag to add inside of the head tag. The only difference is that they use a different id.

Is it safe to simply embed both scripts on the same page? Do I need to write my own Javascript to combine them?

I'm worried that adding both scripts might result in only one of the tags registering. Google ads is warning me that it's not getting conversion events. And Google analytics stopped reporting visitors after I added the Google ads script.

Also, Google analytics seems to have an option to suppress registering duplicate tags on the same page. Google analytics doesn't explain if it is smart enough to realize if there are two tags with the same id or two tags with a different id.

Is there a way to have Google analytics and Google ads crawl my page and tell me that their tag is working?